# Wordpressデータベース独自プラグイン

Tags: php, wordpress

アンケートサイトを作成しています。
各アンケートと回答ButtonにはそれぞれIDが割り付けられています。
そのButtonをクリックすればAjax送受信し、回答結果がシームレスに表示されます。

データベースはWordPressで使用しているデータベースにして
WordPressのWP_POSTに「回答」の新しいカラムを追加し、
記事記入画面にその質問の回答をコンボボックスなどで選択できるようにしたいです。

記事にはアンケートの数だけ`<form>`があり、割り当てられたIDをデータベースで処理します。

以前まで別のデータベースで処理していたんですが、
記事を作成したあとに、いちいちデータベースに「回答」を振り分けなければなりません。
こういうのはプラグインを作らなければならないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> こういうのはプラグインを作らなければならないのでしょうか？

やりたいことが明確でないので、はい/いいえ とも答えられなくて一般論になってしまいますが。

a. プラグインを導入する
b. WordPressの機能でできるないか検討する
c. プラグインを作る

おすすめとしては(a)ですが、必要要件を満たすことが難しい場合は、
(a')としてプラグインを改造する あるいは、

(b)WordPressの機能で満たせるかを検討することになります。
この場合プラグインをつくるというよりは、functions.phpやテーマのカスタマイズにより達成できるかを検討するということです。

それでもだめなら(c)という流れです。

必要な機能要件としては文面から察するに:
1. 回答はAjaxで処理させ、その結果を画面遷移せずに即時表示させる。
2. wp_postテーブルに回答選択肢をカラムとして追加（列持ち）として保持する。
3. 投稿画面に回答選択肢をカスタムフィールドなどで設定させる。

3については列持ちではなく縦持ちにするのが良いかと思います。
そして、WordPressのコアテーブルに選択肢を保持するのではなく、新たにアンケートテーブルと、回答選択子テーブル、回答結果テーブルの3つを新設して管理するのがよいかと思いました。

開発者視点で考えるとプラグインを作ったほうが早そうですが、
もうすこし情報があればさらになにか言えると思います。